# Problema con ciclo do..while que no se repite debidamente

Tags: java, bucles

He elaborado este programa y funciona bien, sin embargo no coordina el ciclo `Do...While`
Es decir, necesito que una vez dado (el numero invertido), me siga imprimiendo la misma pregunta, con el fin de que se siga repitiendo el ciclo, hasta que finalmente cuando asigne el valor 0, el programa finalice correctamente.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MetodoParaInvertir {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num, n, resultado=0;

    num= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un numero entero: ")); 
    System.out.println ("El numero ingresado es : "+num);

    do {
    n = num % 10; 
    num = num / 10;                                       
    resultado = resultado * 10 + n;


    } while (num != 0);
    System.out.println (" \nY su reves es: " +resultado); 

    if ( resultado >0 ) {                                

    num= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Nuevamente Un Numero: ")); 
    System.out.println ("El numero ingresado es : "+num);
    System.out.println (" \nSu reves es: " +resultado); 

    }   
    if (resultado <0) {
    System.out.println (" \nFin del ciclo! ");
    }   
}
   }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor modifica el título de tu pregunta, la misma empieza por dos palabras prohibidas en los títulos. Aquí se te ayuda siempre, y esa ayuda llega lo más urgente que los usuarios pueden responder. No entiendo cómo se ejecuta tu código cada vez, si estás en el `main` ¿ ?

Comment: Además de lo que ha dicho @A.Cedano deberías también formatear apropiadamente el código para que no quede como texto

Comment: Hola Julian Andres, lee [ask] y sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. Deberías dar una breve descripción del código (qué es lo que hace, que resultado esperas) y del problema (qué resultado obtienes). Tal y como está redactada la pregunta ahora mismo, no termina de quedar del todo claro.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar no sé que haces usando `System.out.println()` cuando la clase `JOptionPane` posee el método `showMessageDialog()` que permite mostrar los datos ingresados mediante `showInputDialog()`.

En segundo lugar, según entiendo tu pregunta, deseas que si el usuario ingresa el número `0` tu programa se cierre y sino, que siga preguntando por un número. Para esto, solo basta hacer uso de un `do-while` general.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MetodoParaInvertir
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int numero, auxiliar, resto, resultado;

    do {
      numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número entero: ")); //numero en lugar de num
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El número ingresado es: " + numero);

      if (numero == 0)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fin del ciclo.");
      }
      else
      {
        auxiliar = numero;
        resultado = 0; //aquí reseteamos el valor de resultado

        while (auxiliar != 0) //cambié el do-while por un while
        {
          resto = auxiliar % 10; //resto en vez de n
          resultado = resultado * 10 + resto;
          auxiliar = auxiliar / 10;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El revés del número ingresado es: " + resultado);
      }
    } while (numero != 0);
  }
}
```

He agregado la variable `auxiliar` de modo que sea con esta variable que se lleven a cabo los cálculos para hallar el número invertido del número original. De otro modo, si trabajamos con la variable `numero`, esta terminará siendo igual a `0` y así la condición `numero != 0` al final del `do-while` será siempre falsa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta amigo, ya entendi donde radicaba mi error, un amigo me explico que debia declarar if (numero==0). Nuevamente gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

No deberías trabajar con el número ingresado directamente, deberías almacenarlo en una variable aparte

```
falta = num;
```

El bucle debería ser así

```
do{
    n = falta % 10;
    resultado = resultado * 10 + resto;
    falta = falta / 10;
}while(falta != 0);
```

Comment: Hola men, gracias por responder...                                                        
hice lo que me dijiste y adicionalmente añadí una condicion, (if) , sin embargo a la hora de imprimir nuevamente la pregunta en la condición, repite el resultado anterior nuevamente y se cierra...                     Necesito que siga repitiendose el ciclo, cada vez que asigne un valor, vuelve y me pregunte lo mismo, hasta que asigne el valor (0), y finalize automaticamente.

Comment: creo que deberias explicar mejor lo que buscas y editar tu pregunta original